# KVO on AudioSession isOtherAudioPlaying doesn't work

Tags: ios, audio, key-value-observing, avaudiosession

I'm trying to get notified whenever other audio is being played. I wanted to use KVO for this as `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying]` is a Property of the audio-session.

My registration as an observer:

```
//start KVO on otherAudioIsPlaying
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] addObserver:self
                                      forKeyPath:@"isOtherAudioPlaying"
                                         options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                                         context:nil];
```

My corresponding method:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
NSLog(@"observe fired");
}
```

Why is this not working? AVAudioSession should be KVO compliant if it responts to the valueForKey selector, right?

My audiosession is set active before registering as observer. In addition `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers` is set for the session, which is the reason, why i don't receive regular interruptions, so maybe this is the problem?

Not even the deprecated function works:

`AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying, otherAudioPlaying , (__bridge void *)(self));`

But if i repeatedly print `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudiPlaying]` the value changes as expected.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: I'm running into this myself. Did you ever come up with a solution?